# Amazon Web Services 503 error

Tags: http-status-code-503

We have been trouble shooting a 503 error stating servers are at capacity.

we have removed the potential problems after monitoring the time stamp of the occurence.  Everything tests healthy in our dashboard, we stopped instances and restarted them, as well as creating new instances to see if that would help.  It is not a big website so we are nowhere near capacity..

Sorry On to the question...Has anybody run into this problem and how did they go about trouble shooting beyond what we have already done.

Thanks,

Comment: What were the potential problems? Can you provide some kind of log? What kind of AWS service are you using? What other technologies are in use?

Comment: We didn't get the service with the logs, so we don't have that info for you. We looked at the monitoring of the instance and came to the conclusion that we got the error when when created the ami..We are using the EC2 service..Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer...When we created our new AMI in AWS for our new Instance. We had an AMI that had the same image and no code deployment. So the two AMI's cancelled eachother out and our load balancer just stopped and didn't serv up anything else...

We had to Terminate the AMI, stop and restart the app instances and the and most importantly had to go to code deployment and re deploy the code.

Hope this helps somebody else down the road.